# "This serves as a quick reference to verifying resource availabilities in Espresso"

Tags: grammaticality

What is the correct way of expressing the following sentence?

> This serves as a quick reference to verifying resource availabilities in Espresso.
>   This serves as a quick reference to verify resource availabilities in Espresso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a reference to *ways* that you could verify resource availability? In that case, the first is preferable, but you may want to clarify that:

> This is a quick reference to methods for verifying resource availability in Espresso.

Otherwise, what @Thursagen said.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's the second one:

> This serves as a quick reference to verify resource availabilities in Espresso.

If you were to use the first option, I would change "to" to "for".

> This serves as a quick reference for verifying resource availabilities in Espresso.

Edit:

Or as Karl states below, one could always try the alternative:

> This serves as a quick check to verify availability of resources in Espresso.

This alternative is to make the meaning and intent clearer.

Comment: +1, but also note that it's dubious to pluralize "availability". "resource availability in Espresso" is fine, but "the availability of resources in Espresso" might be better. Using a "reference" to verify the availability of resources also strikes me as a bit awkward, but I can't think of better phrasing off the top of my head...